# String parsing algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, parsing, string-parsing

Regular expressions are a good way to parse regular strings, but when the strings becomes more complex, the regex becomes n² times more complex.

**What is the general approach to string parsing in general?**

For example. I currently have defined a syntax (`{who}[{where}].{what} = {value}`) that can or cannot define certain components.
It's simple enough to be easily understood but complex enough to require a large regex.

Generally, the are some components that can be omitted, however, there are certain components that depends on other components. Example:

```
'key = value' => {
    who: null,
    where: null,
    what: 'key',
    value: 'value'
}

'me.key = value' => {
    who: 'me',
    where: null,
    what: 'key',
    value: 'value'
}

'me[here].key = value' => {
    who: 'me',
    where: 'here',
    what: 'key',
    value: 'value'
}

'me[here] = value' => 'Error! Need to specify *what*.'

'[here].key = value' => 'Error! Need to specify *who* if *where* is specified.'
```

Comment: The general approach is to define your grammar and then write a parser for it. Most languages have parser libraries or parser generators available for them. The grammar will determine what kind of parser (e.g. LALR) you need to parse it.

Comment: I don't know what you call "a large regex", but the (real life) pattern to describe your grammar is easy and not very long: https://regex101.com/r/OeQcUO/1

Comment: You may try to implement parsing based on [BNF notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus–Naur_form), like [here](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566565/2165759).